# How to auto populate a field in django when a value is selected from dropdown menu in another field in forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-widget

I have two models that are located in two different apps;
**Invoice** and **Inventory**.

**InvoiceModel:**

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    line_one = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, to_field='title', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', blank=True, null=True, related_name='+', verbose_name="Line 1")
    line_one_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    line_one_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    line_one_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Invoice.line_one** is referenced to **Inventory.title**

**InventoryModel**:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
  product_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  product = models.TextField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
  amount = models.IntegerField('Unit Price', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

So basically the user adds a product using the **Inventory** model and then in the **Invoice** model, they'll have a drop-down menu for **line_one** and when they click a certain item, I want the **line_one_unit_price** to get populated with the price of the item selected in the **line_one** option!

**InvoiceForm:**

```
class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    line_one_unit_price = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select, label="Unit Price(₹)")
    
    class Meta:
      model = Invoice
      fields = ['line_one',#...]
    
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['line_one_unit_price'].widget.choices = [(i.amount, i.amount) for i in Inventory.objects.all()]
```

By using the above logic, I can list the amount of all products present in the Inventory but I want it to only display the amount of the product that the user has selected in **line_one**.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

In the image, the amount of the first product is automatically added but instead, I want it to be "-----" by default.
How can I implement that? Thank you.

Comment: It's a little strange that your `Invoice.line_one` is a foreign key to the `title` instead of the primary key.  If you ever need to change the name of an `Inventory` item then you'll need to update every invoice.

Comment: @TimTisdall Sorry. I'm new. If `Invoice.line_one` is a foreign key to the `product.number` i.e., the primary key then `line_one` will have a dropdown menu of product numbers which isn't what I want. So I thought that relationship made more sense.

Comment: Every table has a default `id` primary key.  If you remove the `to_field='title'` then it'll default to using the primary key.  If you want `product_number` to be the primary key then you need to add a `primary_key=True` to that field, otherwise the default `id` field will be used as the primary key.  To fix the display, you should use a `ModelChoiceField` and specify which thing to display.

Comment: I did use `ModelChoiceField` once but it was just when I had a few choices in mind but in this case, I want the list of objects to act like a choicelist and I'm not sure how I can do that? Thank you

Comment: You still are using `ModelChoiceField` for `line_one` as that's the default and you haven't overridden it.  I'm saying you need a `line_one = forms.ModelChoiceField()` with additional settings to get it to display correctly instead of using `to_field`.  Don't modify your database schema purely to make the form look correct, you can always modify the form.

Comment: @TimTisdall Thank you! You're right. I am now displaying the lines using the `ModelChoiceField` and also gave `product_number` as the primary key. 
Can you please tell me the name of the concept I am searching for based on my current question? i.e., to want the appropriate price displayed based on the object? So that I can search more about it on the internet.

Comment: @TimTisdall After referencing the foreign ley, I am getting this, `ValueError at /invoice/add_invoice/
Cannot assign "'Asus T'": "Invoice.line_one" must be a "Inventory" instance.`
T-T

Comment: If you want one field to dynamically change whenever you change another, my answer below covers that.

Comment: @TimTisdall I tried this code: 
`def add_invoice(request):
    form = InvoiceForm(request.POST or None)
    data = Inventory.objects.all()
    dict_obj = model_to_dict(data)
    serialized = json.dumps(dict_obj)
 #...

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/invoice/list_invoice')
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "serialized":serialized,
    }
    return render(request, "entry.html", context)`
Is that the correct way? I am not sure how I can access that JSON object in javascript?

Comment: Sorry, this question is now getting out of control...  If you run into specific problems, you can try posting new questions.  I will say that you now have the data in a string, so you can do `my_data = {{ serialized }}` in the template (within a `<script>` block) and then you can access `my_data` within the JavaScript however you like.

Comment: @TimTisdall I am getting this error - `AttributeError at /invoice/add_invoice/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'`. Please tell me how to debug this and I'll stop asking any more questions. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 0):

There's different ways you can do this, but essentially there's no built-in simple way.  You need to employ JavaScript on the front-end to detect when that "Line 1" field changes and then fill in the "Unit Price" accordingly.

If you don't have too many "Line 1" items, one way of doing it is creating your own widget to embed the price in each `<option>` of the drop-down with a `data-` attribute.  Then you include some JavaScript that detects when that drop-down has changed and updates the read-only "Unit Price" field.  On the back-end, you should also make sure you don't use that form field and look-up the price based on the "Line 1" field.

Another option is to make an AJAX call to an endpoint to fetch the price.

**EDIT:**  If there's multiple drop-downs with the same list of items, then having a global JS variable with a price look-up might work best (if not too large).  Generate a look-up `dict` of `product_number` to `amount` (price), pass that to the template to output as JSON in a global variable, and then use that in your JavaScript to populate the "Unit Price".

Comment: I have a total of 10 Lines! Can you please share a link to the documentation or anything really that shows how to fill the Unit Price accordingly?

Comment: Can you please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926096/attributeerror-at-invoice-add-invoice-int-object-has-no-attribute-meta-wh
Thanks