# AttributeError at /invoice/add_invoice/ 'int' object has no attribute '_meta' while using in_bulk

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views, django-serializer

I want to convert the model instances into a JSON object and then pass it to the HTML file. However, I get an AttributeError at this line:
`data = serializers.serialize("json", Inventory.objects.in_bulk())`

The full `views.py`:

```
def add_invoice(request):
  form = InvoiceForm(request.POST or None)
  data = serializers.serialize("json", Inventory.objects.in_bulk())
  total_invoices = Invoice.objects.count()
  queryset = Invoice.objects.order_by('-invoice_date')[:6]

  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved')
    return redirect('/invoice/list_invoice')
  context = {
    "form": form,
    "title": "New Invoice",
    "total_invoices": total_invoices,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "data": data,
  }
return render(request, "entry.html", context)
```

The Javascript code:

```
{{ data|json_script:"hello-data" }}
<script type="text/javascript">
    const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);

    document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(event){
        document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = data[event.target.value].fields.amount;
    };

</script>
```

`models.py`:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
  product_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  product = models.TextField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120, default='', blank=True, unique=True)
  amount = models.IntegerField('Unit Price', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

How can I pass that JSON object and assign the amount value to the text field according to the object selected in the dropdown? Thanks
[image: SS]

EDIT:
Full Trace

> AttributeError at /invoice/add_invoice/
> 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoice/add_invoice/
> Django Version: 4.0
> Exception Type: AttributeError
> Exception Value:
> 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'
> Exception Location: C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py, line 110, in serialize
> Python Executable:  C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.10.0
> Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\Kiran\Desktop\src',
> 'C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.zip',
> 'C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib',
> 'C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310',
> 'C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages']
> Server time:    Sun, 10 Jul 2022 13:45:15 +0000
> Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
> C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request) …
> Local vars
> C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
> Local vars
> C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py, line 21, in *wrapped_view
> return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
> Local vars
> C:\Users\Kiran\Desktop\src\invoicecemgmt\views.py, line 39, in add_invoice
> data = serializers.serialize("json", Inventory.objects.in_bulk()) …
> Local vars
> C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers_*init**.py, line 129, in serialize
> s.serialize(queryset, **options) …
> Local vars
> C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py, line 110, in serialize
> concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model …
> Local vars

EDIT:
Javascript code-

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);

    document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(event){
        var data1 = data.find(({pk}) => pk === event.target.value);
        alert(data1)
        document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = data1 && data1.amount ? data1.amount : 0;
};
```

If I type some primary key in the `data.find()=>1==` then the output works fine. I want to know how to send the primary key of all the objects in the `data.find(())` so that I can find a match with the title selected and retrieve it's amount.
While testing that function with numerical values, I noticed that the site wasn't dynamical? Even though I changed the primary key in the code, It still displayed the `amount` of the previous primary key and it didn't update until and unless I deleted the product from the Inventory.

Comment: @JanMalte Can you please check this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928865/json-dumps-returns-the-objects-as-a-string-instead-of-a-json-object

I really need your help.

Answer (score 1):

The line in your view should be like the following I think.

```py
  data = serializers.serialize("json", Inventory.objects.all())
```