# json.dumps returns the objects as a string instead of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, django, dictionary, jsonparser

In the `views.py`:
`data1 = Inventory.objects.values_list('product_number','amount') data = json.dumps(list(data1), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)`.
I pass `data` as context to the html file.

In the HTML file, Using JS I access the JSON object with this code:

```
{{ data|json_script:"hello-data" }}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);
    document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(event){
            console.log(typeof data)
            alert(data);
            document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = data[this.value];
};

</script>
```

I expect the `var data` to be a dictionary but it seems to be a String. `Object.fromEntries`  is not working and I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Iterator value [ is not an entry object at Function.fromEntries (<anonymous>)`.
`JSON.parse` is removing the double quotation and I get `[[1, 56000], [2, 55000]]` but I am not able to access it as a dictionary. Whenever I use the index to access it, It returns the single characters as output instead of thinking of it as a dict object. How can I convert it into a dictionary? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are obtaining a list from the following line:

```
data1 = list(Inventory.objects.values_list('product_number','amount'))
```

Hence, you are just converting a list to JSON and, then, parsing this JSON, which yields a list.

Try to use the following instead:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.core import serializers
data_obj_model = Inventory.objects.all()
data1=serializers.serialize('json', data_obj_model, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Then, you can access, in your JavaScript code, all the fields of the model using `data["fields"].field_of_interest`.

Or you can also create a custom dictionary with the two fields you were interested in as follows:

```
data1 = dict(Inventory.objects.values_list('product_number','amount'))
```

This could be used as a dictionary in the JavaScript after parsing it.